# Directly using output from OBJECT libraries in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, c++20, clang++

I'm trying to work with c++20 modules with clang using CMake. I need to do the following:

- first, compile the module interface
- then compile all the implementation files - giving the module interface with a flag
- for using the module, again give the module interface with a flag as well as the generated library.

The problem occurs during the first step. The module interface needs to be compiled before everything else, so my idea was to create an OBJECT library (because otherwise CMake will "link" it, which breaks the module interface).

I then need the list of object files (which will be only one, of course), but that seems to be only doable with a generator expression, and I cannot use generator expressions when adding the compiler flags for step 2.

Another idea I had was to compile using `add_custom_command` and `add_custom_target`, but then you run the risk of not properly using the same compile flags (there seems to be no proper way to get *all* the compile flags from a target).

So, to summarize, the structure might be like this:

module-def.cpp (module definition file) -> module-def.pcm
module-impl.cpp (implementation file) -> module-impl.o

I need to compile module-impl.cpp with a `-fmodule-file=<dir>/module-def.pcm`, but I cannot find a good way to do this, since I cannot find a reliable way to get the path to the generated pcm-file.

Comment: I do not follow. I think you want to `set_source_file_properties(the_source_that_depends_on_the_module OBJECT_DEPENDS the_module)`. If something depends on something and CMake doesn't know, tell it to CMake.

Comment: @KamilCuk I don't understand. How does that make CMake add the `-fmodule-file=<object>` to the compile flags?